# Do i need to wait when using system D

Tags: linux, bash, sleep, systemd

So i have found a script that uses sleep after system d command. As far as I'm concerned, it doesn't run asynchronously so the sleep is not necessary, right?

Adding a piece of code, for better understanding.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
sleep 10s
systemctl start $service_name
sleep 10s
```

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. New or updated unit files will be available directly after `systemctl daemon-reload` has completed.